# Identify if a B2C tenant supports login.microsoftonline.com and b2clogin.com

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to verify that our web apps and API will work once Microsoft deprecate the login.microsoftonline.com end point for B2C tenants (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin).

We have a number of B2C tenants used by different environments (production, qa, dev etc).

These have been created at various points over the past couple of years.

To be totally sure I want to run our apps and API against a tenant which only supports the b2clogin endpoint.

However I'm not sure if any our existing B2C tenants were created *after* the announcement from Microsoft on the 4th December 2019 (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/b2c-deprecate-msol/)

Rather than having to create/configure a new tenant for this purpose how do I check our existing B2C tenants to find out which supports only the b2clogin.com? I guess the creation date of the B2C tenant would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of your b2c tenants, and apps, migrate all of them to beclogin.com.

Eventually support will be removed for login.microsoftonline.com for all tenants, so you don't need to find which tenant support ONLY b2clogin.com.

You can ping this endpoint to see if old point still works for you.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=yourpolicyname
```

New endpoint is this

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=yourpolicyname
```

**There is no api which can give you creation date of tenant. You can find creation date of application though from app manifest. Go to app registration, select your app, and then manifest. there is a field called creationDate.**

---

Comment: Yes I understand that. What I want is a B2C tenant created post 4-Dec-19 that only supports b2clogin. This will allow us to test our app and APIs against it without the overhead of creating and configuring a new tenant.